# how to get dataframe subsets having similar values on some columns?

Tags: python, pandas, subset

I'm working on the following dataframe:

```
   height  weight  shoe_size  age
0     175      70         40   30
1     175      75         39   41
2     175      69         40   33
3     176      71         40   35
4     178      81         41   27
5     169      73         38   49
6     170      65         39   30
```

and discovered this Relaxed Functional Dependency (RFD):

```
('weight': 2.0) ==> ('height': 1.0)
```

meaning that for each couple of rows having a difference **<=2** on the weight they would have a difference **<=1** on the height too.

I need to find all the subsets of rows on which this RFD holds, and show the one with more rows.

In this case the best (biggest) subset would be:

```
   height  weight  shoe_size  age
2     175      69         40   33
0     175      70         40   30
3     176      71         40   35
```

How do I get all such subsets from a dataframe or at least the biggest subset for which this RFD holds?

**Update**

I implemented the solution suggested by @DYZ, but it seems like the **threshold** is respected only for single edges and not for the full path from one node to the other of the connected component in the graph.

To better explain what I'm talking about, here an example of the subset found with the following 
**RFD**

```
('height': 1.0, 'age': 6.0) ==> ('weight': 4.0)
```

**Subset**

```
   height  weight  shoe_size  age
0     175      70         40   30
1     175      75         39   41
2     175      69         40   33
3     176      71         40   35
```

This subset is wrong because the rows

```
   height  weight  shoe_size  age
0     175      70         40   30
```

and

```
   height  weight  shoe_size  age
1     175      75         39   41
```

have a distance of **11 > 6**, on the **age**, as well as a distance of **5 > 4** on the **weight**.

I think this may be because it's considered the adjacency matrix instead of a distance matrix for the graph, so a row is added if there is at least one edge respecting the threshold, but it should actually be there if all the paths in the connected components respect the thresholds.

Comment: why is index 0 included in your desired output? The weight difference between that row and the next is > 2

Comment: Because 69 and 70 have a distance of 1, which is <= 2, as well as 69 and 71 having a distance of 2 <= 2, and 70 having a distance of 1<=2 from 71.
Same logic for their corresponding values on the height column having a distance <= 1

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There may be a better solution to your problem. I am going to show how to find the answer using graph theory (namely, module `networkx`).

```
import networkx as nx
import numpy as np
```

Start by isolating the columns that are involved in the RFD calculation:

```
values = df[['height', 'weight']].values
```

Calculate all possible differences. This is an `O(N^2)` operation and may be costly in terms of time and memory.

```
dist = np.abs(values[:,None] - values)
```

Identify the suitable pairs of rows:

```
im = (dist[:,:,0] <= 1) & (dist[:,:,1] <= 2)
```

Use them as an adjacency matrix and construct a graph. The graph nodes represent rows in the original dataframe. The nodes are connected if the corresponding rows are in the RFD:

```
G = nx.from_numpy_matrix(im)
```

Find all cliques in the graph (subgraphs where any node is connected directly to any other node). Sort the cliques by size and choose the largest. Extract the namesake rows from the original dataframe:

```
df.loc[sorted(nx.clique.find_cliques(G), key=len)[-1],:]
#   height  weight  shoe_size  age
#0     175      70         40   30
#2     175      69         40   33
#3     176      71         40   35
```

Comment: Thanks @DYZ, maybe the graph should have weights on the paths, and a connected component should be composed of just paths respecting the thresholds. May you have a look at the update in the question?

Comment: I misunderstood your question. You need cliques, not connected components. Will change the answer later.

Comment: Thanks a lot, now it works as expected.
I tried also nx.clique.make_max_clique_graph() to plot the graph but it is not the same nodes. Is it possible to plot this clique?

Comment: There is nothing interesting in it: by definition, a clique is a full graph (each node is connected to each node).